# for loop doesn't loop to next element python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am trying to loop through a list. But it is getting the first element. It doesn't gets the second element. I can't figure out what i am doing wrong.

```
filte = ['fingerprint','cipher']
dupe = ['cipher','extract']

for val in filte:
    print(val)
    if val in dupe:
        dupe.remove(val)
    else:
        filte.remove(val)

print("filter",filte)
print("dupe",dupe)
```

output i got:

```
fingerprint
filter ['cipher']
dupe ['cipher', 'extract']
```

required output:

```
fingerprint
cipher
filter ['cipher']
dupe [ 'extract']
```

Comment: I don't exactly know how loops work in Python, but as you are removing an element during the loop, it mays bring an iterating issue. It's waiting for a second element, but after removing, `cipher` becomes the first one, so there is no second.

Comment: Exactly. So OP you want to either iterate on a reversed list (deleting its last element does not alter its indexes) or build a new list where you append the element that are suitable.

Comment: Could you explain @SmackAlpha what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set`

**Ex:**

```
filte = ['fingerprint','cipher']
dupe = ['cipher','extract']

print(list(set(filte) - set(dupe)))  #OR list(set(filte).difference(set(dupe)))
print(list(set(dupe) - set(filte)))
```

**Output:**

```
['fingerprint']
['extract']
```

**Note:** Not a good practice to remove elements while iterating the object.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `else`

```py
filte = ['fingerprint','cipher']
dupe = ['cipher','extract']

for val in filte:
    print(val)
    if val in dupe:
        dupe.remove(val)
        filte.remove(val)

print("filter",filte)
print("dupe",dupe)
```

output:

```
fingerprint
cipher
filter ['fingerprint']
dupe ['extract']
```